# Render function branch not getting covered in react test case

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a Pure Component but i am not getting the render function branch covered in the test cases.What could be the reason

Comment: Please post your component code and the test case too

Comment: With this amount of information, we can only answer an unhelpful "you did something wrong", sorry